# sorting array of objects by property

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to ios development and I'm trying to sort a tableview that gets populated by an array. I've looked into other solutions and for some reason the tableview isn't populating correctly. The array sorts in ascending order, but then the tableview doesn't display the objects in the correct order.

Here is what I have for the sorting:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"_miles"
                                             ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray = [_addObjects sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
_objects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:sortedArray];
```

Here is my cellforrow :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //NSLog(@"%@", _objects);

    VenuesTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    CustomObject *currentObject = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.venuesTitle.text = [currentObject nameOfVenue];
    NSString *preDistance = @"about";
    NSString *postDistance = @"miles";


    cell.venuesSubTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", preDistance,[_miles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ,postDistance];

    if (cell != nil) {
        NSMutableString *imagePath = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [_paths objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [cell.venuesImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        [cell.venuesImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imagePath] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder@2x.png"]];

    }
    return cell;
}
```

when I log out the _objects array I get them in the right order, but they're not appearing in the right order in the tableview (the objects have a miles property that I'm trying to sort by).

Comment: Are you adding new objects after the table view has already been displayed on the screen? You need to manually send `[tableView reloadData]`.

Comment: Also there's a bunch of stuff you should be doing differently in your code, if you want I can offer some advice how to code things properly?

Comment: Yes. I have a reloadData right after the sort. And yes I would love some help!

Comment: I'm not sure why the sort isn't working then, it should, maybe you can post more code/details?

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but here is the full .m: http://pastebin.com/2bAcGSbG

Comment: @StevenP. I'd suggest a radical redesign of your parsing code, eliminating all of those redundant arrays (which become immediately meaningless as soon as you sort the results). See http://pastie.org/8997624. I've also tweaked `CustomObject` (as I think you want to keep data in its original format, and where you need a "pretty" representation of the distance in miles or the full address, write methods to do that). Anyway, getting rid of all of those extra arrays will eliminate the current disconnect between the sorted array, and all of those other arrays you have.

Comment: That solves your immediate problem and also fixes a few other little bugs (you were doing `alloc` of `CustomObject` only once; I think you might have been sorting distances alphabetically rather than numerically, sometimes you referenced `_myTableView`, sometimes `self.tableView`; etc.). I haven't done substantive testing of that code, but hopefully it illustrates the technique of parsing JSON results without creating all of those extra arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You are sorting your array, `_addObjects` by `miles` and storing the result in `_objects`, but then, when you're displaying the results, you're not accessing `miles` from that sorted array you just created, but rather looking it up in some other array.

I don't know when you're populating that separate `_miles` array, but I'd suggest you retire it entirely and just make sure you get and set the `miles` property from the `CustomObject` instances. (Same for `_paths` ... this should probably be a property of your `CustomObject`, not a separate array.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything obvious, but a couple things that are a bit strange:

You should not use `_objects`. Always use `self.objects` instead. Most programming languages make it completely impossible to access pointers directly like you are doing here, and for good reason. It's dangerous and can lead to confusing bugs like this one. You should pretty much never access a property using `_foobar`. Always use `self.foobar`.

Why are you using `NSMutableArray` instead of `NSArray`? Are you sure there isn't code somewhere else modifying it?

Where does `VenuesTableViewCell *cell` get created? I don't see anywhere in your code that one of these objects is created. `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier..]` never creates a new cell, it always returns an existing one or `nil` if none exists. Your code isn't throwing an assertion error (I assume?), so obviously it never returns `nil`. But there's something weird going on if that doesn't return `nil` the first time you call it?

Comment: there might be reasons not to access a ivar through a property: not to trigger KVO, apple documents say not to use it in init and dealloc,… your NEVER is quite too harsh.

Comment: also you are wrong about cell creation: `VenuesTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];` does create a cell if it has none to recycle, but a class must be registered.

Comment: [A UITableViewCell object with the associated reuse identifier. This method always returns a valid cell.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW88)

Comment: @Abhi By the way, to add to vikingosegundo's point, also if you use storyboards and cell prototypes, it's even easier, and no manual manual registering of the class is needed, at all. Bottom line, the use of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` in the question is fine. But I do agree with your accessor method comments, as it's rarely the right solution to be bypassing accessors (other than initializer methods, `dealloc`, and custom setters). Vikingosegundo is technically right that there might be isolated cases where you'd bypass it, but there's serious code smell if you do.

Comment: Sure it is code smell not to use the property at least as setter, but the *never* is too strong. and it is surely not part of the problem. so basically this answer does not even try to answer the real question and should be posted in the form of comments.

Comment: Thanks guys for the associated re-use identifier thing. I didn't know it existed... iOS 6+ I see. Also, I think Apple's documentation on avoiding KVO/etc during init/dealloc is no-longer valid. That only applies to non-ARC code and it was debatable whether it actually applied or not even before then. There are many Obj-C programmers, including some who worked for NeXT before Apple purchased the company, who advocate always using accessor methods, even inside init/dealloc. And some of Apple's sample code does use it inside init/dealloc.

Comment: I've used getters/setters almost exclusively for more than 10 years. Never had a problem caused by it, except occasionally performance issues... which were usually solved by switching to C structs instead of objects, or even just huge blobs of NSData with values manually encoded into it (handy when you need part of your RAM to sit in virtual memory).

Comment: why do you bring up history and setter and getter now? If you look on Robs and mine reputation you'll see that we don't need private tutoring, but thanks. There are the possibility that in rare cases properties will break in initializers, especially if you do KVO and the state of the object is not complete yet, but the listening object assumes it. this has nothing to do with ARC and is still in the docs. also niling out a property can lead to confusion.properties aren't solely about memory management. anyway: your answer does not address the question.

Comment: and to be clear: I also advocate to use properties, unless for named reasons. but accessing ivars through properties won't affect OPs problem.